# Why does my method declaration generate an inconsistent accessibility error?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I am acessing data from data base with the following code,

```
IList<MyListDB> MyList = this.GetMyList();
```

and the **GetMyList()** function,

```
public IList<MyListDB> GetMyList()
    {
        IList<MyListDB> MyList = null;
        using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<MyListDB> EmpQuery = from Emp in db.Details select Emp;
            MyList = EmpQuery.ToList();
        }
        return MyList;
    }
```

But i get a error stating that,

```
Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyExpense.Values.MyListDB>' is less accessible than method 'MyExpense.Values.MyPanorama.GetMyList()'
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyListDB` type needs to be declared as `public`.

Your method is public and hence the type it returns needs to be public as well (if it wasn't, how else would you access it from anywhere?).